# How do Design this XML file of spinner

Tags: xml, android-layout, layout, material-design, android-spinner

Here i am attaching a screenshot of the design please help me its a project and i m new in android [image]

Comment: Edited the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

Firstly create a drawable file

**spinner_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        <solid android:color="#F5F5F5"/>
        <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#454551"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Now, use `spinner_bg.xml` into layout file as background,Code for layout file is as below:

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#F5F5F5"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product Group"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Literature"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:background="#F5F5F5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is Output for above code:

[image]

[image]

I hope its work for you.